# Conditional compilation in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I am working on a library which depends on Scala 2.9 but only for a minor feature. I would like to propose version compatible with 2.8, but I don't want to maintain two code branch. Since I'm using SBT, I would like to benefits from it cross-compilation features.

However I don't know is there is a way to provide an equivalent of conditional compilation, to include a piece of code only if Scala 2.9 is used. Reflexivity could be an option (but how?).

**Edit:** The features I am using in 2.9 are the new `sys` package object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it with reflection. So if I want to get the `sys.SystemProperties`, I can do:

```
try {
    val k = java.lang.Class.forName("scala.sys.package$")
    val m = k.getMethod( "props" )
    // etc.
} catch {
    case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only available with Scala 2.9")
}
```

But it is so boring and ugly that I think I will drop those features...

Comment: Shouldn't you catch stuff like `NoSuchMethodException`?

Comment: I catch everything because all steps of reflexion can result in throwing exceptions.

Comment: Fair enough. When doing that kind of stuff I usually unwrap `InvocationTargetException`s to make it more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Read this blog post, which describes how to do it with metaprogramming:

http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/meta-programming-with-scala-conditional-compilation-and-loop-unrolling/

Comment: Merci! But since I am referencing code which don't exist in Scala 2.8 (see edit), it won't compile.