# Conditional compilation of code blocks in Scala

Tags: scala, compilation, conditional-compilation, scala-macros, scala.js

I was wondering if there is a way to conditionally exclude a block of code from being compiled in Scala using compile-time flags (i.e. some rough equivalent of the C family's `#define`). I am aware that there is no direct counterpart, and I don't think Scala's macros are what I need, so I was wondering if there is another way to do this.

In my current case specifically (and I provide this only as an example, because I've had other cases in the past that prompted the same question), I am building a library in ScalaJS. The library is a front-end component, and will primarily be used by my application - which is also using ScalaJS. However, I would like to allow this component to be called by native Javascript in other projects that are not using ScalaJS. As such, I want to have a user-configurable flag that will toggle the exporting of symbols to native Javascript upon request.

It makes no sense for these flags to be exported by default (in my application), since the only other code calling it will be other ScalaJS code, and thus having the overhead of exported symbols is pointless. Maintaining two separate code branches for something so trivial also seems like a futile effort.

This is basically what I have in mind (pseudo-code, of course):

```
...

#if JS_EXPORT
@JSExport
#endif
case class componentProps(
    #if JS_EXPORT
    @(JSExport @field) 
    #endif
    val propertyOne: Int
    #if JS_EXPORT
    @(JSExport @field) 
    #endif
    val propertyTwo: String
)

...
```

*I am well aware that there is no pre-processor and the above is intended as pseudo-code only. I was just wondering if there is a way of accomplishing something similar, without unnecessary overhead such as using reflection (because I'm sure that would provide a bigger performance hit than just exporting by default).*

Also, I was able to find this question: [Conditional compilation in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579661/conditional-compilation-in-scala). But that is not what I need.

Comment: You could build your own simple preprocessor as an sbt `sourceGenerator`.

Comment: @sjrd That would be an interesting project as a way for me to get deeper into Scala. However, this question was also to gauge the general sentiment towards something like this and make sure there is nothing wrong with my own thinking (i.e. maybe I'm misunderstanding something) when wanting such a feature, because to me it is a no-brainer. Do you think there would be interest in such a thing?

Comment: maybe you try to use  elidable ,although has some different `#default`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388952/what-does-the-elidable-annotation-do-in-scala-and-when-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way which isn't a complete hack to do it within the source code.

The standard ways to accomplish dual JVM/JS projects are to minimize the number of source files where a difference occurs, and to do it by hand for those (almost all of Li Haoyi's projects are like this--check out the structure of fastparse for example); or to have two git branches which have the two variants and merge all changes from one to the other.

Comment: This is what I was afraid to hear. I am really surprised that no one has yet come up with a preprocessor for Scala, especially because Scala has SO many features for every imaginable use case, but one that is so basic (and that would be applicable to quite a number of use-cases, most especially desktop apps) is missing. Unless it's me who is missing something. It, however, almost appears natural for something like this to be available at the very least as an sbt task.

Comment: Minimizing the number of places/source-files that platform-specific code lives is generally a good practice, completely independently of Scala.js =)

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you do not need to have specific source code to do that: Scala.js provides the `scalajs-stubs` library. This is a JVM targeted library that contains stub annotations for Scala.js annotations (`@JSExport` et al.).

You can add it as a "provided" dependency to your JVM project, so it won't be needed at runtime:

```
libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-js" %% "scalajs-stubs" % scalaJSVersion % "provided"
```

Note that the annotations are not static, i.e. they won't even appear in the `.class` files.

More details on [scala-js.org](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/cross-build.html) (bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful to know, but doesn't directly relate to my case because my project is not dual-target ScalaJS/JVM; instead, it is two versions of ScalaJS (one for export to be used by raw Javascript, one for usage by other ScalaJS code).